# What is the difference between msfvenom and msfpayload

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

I'm using Kali 2.0

I have tried msfpayload, i faced some error saying

```
bash : msfpayload: command not found
```

And now I come to know msfvenom is also does the same thing

So my question is what is the difference between msfvenom and msfpayload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/):

> msfvenom is a combination of Msfpayload and Msfencode, putting both of these tools into a single Framework instance. Note: msfvenom has replaced both msfpayload and msfencode as of June 8th, 2015.